# Why should I use the Item Modification Table?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

It seems that any modification you can do to a weapon on the Item Modification Table can also be done from Inventory.

Why are there so many tables and why would I want to use them?

Comment: good question I have asked myself that alot also. The only improvement I would see is if you could look at multiple items to see if the mods on one is better than on another. But I have not tried to use them much and not sure if that is the case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATE: New features to the game including customizing augments. This feature requires the Item Modification Tables now. See Matthew Read's answer. The original answer that applies to the game as it was originally released, is still included here:

ORIGINAL:

It is a remnant from earlier item modification game mechanics Bioware was trying.

Currently the Item Modification Table has no special purpose. You can modify an already-modifiable item by <kbd>Ctrl + Right Mouse Click</kbd>-ing the item in your character or inventory window. You can still use the table to start this process if you want, but you don't need to.

EDIT: One on each starter planet is also used as the target of a "how to use item mods" intro quest.

Comment: it's for people who like to roleplay ;)

Comment: wow, I didn't know that you didn't need the tables... thanks!

Comment: So if you use some provided table it doesn't cost money, but if you yank the things out in the middle of the woods, you get charged...

Comment: @NickT: I'll check later to confirm, but I believe it costs money to remove mods even with the table.

Comment: Yes, removing mods costs the same with or without the table, so I can see no practical reason for them to exist.

Comment: Thanks. That saved me a lot of running. But it is bad design and communication from bioware part.

Comment: to tell you the truth, I don't know why they're still there. I joined beta like 3 or 4 months ago and at the time you already didn't need them. Maybe they have some future plans for it?

Comment: They do use one on each starter planet still as the target for the "how to use item mods" intro quest.

Answer (score 7):

The Item Modification Stations are now required to add Augments to your gear.  When you buy an Augmentation Kit you have to take it to one of the stations and pay to apply it to your gear, giving you an augment slot.  You can then use the station to add an augment or simply modify the gear as normal with Ctrl + Right Click.  (They still allow you to adjust other mods with the stations.)

Augments are exactly the same as other mods, they add extra stats.  All equippable items can be augmented.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have noticed: For example, I have 2 guns in my inventory that are non-mod. However, they pop up when I use the modification stations, allowing me to add and extract modifications there when I was unable to in my inventory.

Comment: this sounds more like a bug.